# Get Picklist value not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, dynamic-picklist, getpicklistvalues, getobjectinfo

I have been trying to get the picklist values dynamically in LWC without using the Apex Code but somehow I am unable to get them. Not sure what is the actual problem

```
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import PROCESSING_USER_TEAM from '@salesforce/schema/User.Processing_User_Team__c';

export default class Wtclm_DocExecAllocation extends LightningElement {

    @track teams;
    selectedTeam = 'None';
    @api objectName = 'User';
    @api fieldName = 'Processing_User_Team__c';

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: USER_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: PROCESSING_USER_TEAM
    })
    pickValues({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.teams = data.values.map(plValue => {
                return {
                    label: plValue.label,
                    value: plValue.value
                };
            });

        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }


<lightning-combobox
            name="teams"
            label="Teams"
            value={selectedTeam}
            placeholder="Select Team"
            options={teams}
            onchange={handleSelectedTeam} ></lightning-combobox>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with dynamic and reactive object property `$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId`. From the [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

> In the wire adapter’s configuration object, prefix a value with $ to
> reference a property of the component instance. The $ prefix tells the
> wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as
> this.propertyName

Reactive property allows LWC to handle changes done to that property and invoke `wire` function every time, this property is changed automatically. But this property should be a direct field of LWC class.

You need to store `objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId` in a separate field.

```
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import PROCESSING_USER_TEAM from '@salesforce/schema/User.Processing_User_Team__c';

export default class Wtclm_DocExecAllocation extends LightningElement {

    @track teams;
    selectedTeam = 'None';
    @api objectName = 'User';
    @api fieldName = 'Processing_User_Team__c';
    objectInfoData;
    defaultRecordTypeId;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: USER_OBJECT })
    wireObjectInfo({ error, data }){
        if(data){
            this.objectInfoData = data; // if you still need it
            this.defaultRecordTypeId = data.defaultRecordTypeId;
        } else if (error) {
             //handle error
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: PROCESSING_USER_TEAM
    })
    pickValues({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.teams = data.values.map(plValue => {
                return {
                    label: plValue.label,
                    value: plValue.value
                };
            });

        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer still it is not working I tried to see console of the return response of get object info and I am seeing that data.defaultRecordTypeId is coming as null for the user object. FYI there is no record type available for the User object except master.

Comment: @Sam-dev-sfdc makes sense, as we can't create recordtypes for `User` can you try to hardcode value `012000000000000AAA` instead of `$defaultRecordTypeId` ?

Comment: I did try the same but it didn't work it was throwing an error Invalid record Type id. At last, I used the apex class to get the picklist value